# Count contents of one column if an adjacent cell matches a query in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I have a spreadsheet maintained in Numbers where I record my practices at the range, which lists type of weapon (pistol, rifle, shotgun), as well as the numbers of shots fired.

I am readily able to calculate the total, but want a more granular overview.

The column recording numbers of shots is called "skudd", while the one recording type of weapon is called type. The formula I've got right now is:

```
COUNT(Skudd;COUNTIF(Type;"Pistol"))
```

This should return something over 1500 shots, but currently returns the result 28. The number of times at the range shooting pistol is 18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SUMIF](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH802) instead of `COUNTIF`. `SUMIF` let's you search for a value in one range and accumulate values in another range if a match is found. `COUNTIF` counts the occurrences of a match, which is why you're getting lower than expected results.

Let's say I have two columns: **Type** and **Count**. Here's our sample data:

[image: Our Sample Data]

If I want to `SUMIF` all the **Count** values when **Type** is value `A` I'd use:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A7, "A", B2:B7)
```

Doing this for values `A`, `B` and `C` yields the correct results on our simple data set so we can convince ourselves this is what we actually want:

[image: The Simple Results]

So, in your case, you'd want to do something like:

```
=SUMIF(<range where you keep gun type>, "Pistol", <range where you keep shots fired>)
```

And that would give you the total shots fired any time you recorded the gun type as `Pistol`.

Note, it's not necessary for the columns to be adjacent, which is nice. But they should have a similar range or odd things can happen.