# Count checked cells if cell on same row matches state in Numbers

Tags: numbers

Following on from [my previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204465/count-contents-of-one-column-if-an-adjacent-cell-matches-a-query-in-numbers), I also record which entry records a competition. These are currently recorded as checkboxes. Counting them all is easy enough; I simply use the following function:

```
=COUNTIF(Stevne?;TRUE)
```

However, I also want to count the competitions that are specific to a type of firearm.

What I've got so far is:

```
=COUNTIF(Stevne?;TRUE;AND(Type:"Pistol"))
```

That, unfortunately, returns a Syntax error, and I can't understand why.

Comment: On a hunch, I tried this, still no luck, though: =COUNTIF(Stevne?;TRUE);AND(Type:"Pistol")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `COUNTIFS()` function.

So in this case:

`=COUNTIFS («gun range», true, «Firearm», "Pistol")`

Accounting for `;` delimiters:

`=COUNTIFS («gun range»; true; «Firearm»; "Pistol")`

[image: COUNTIFS function]

From the help:

> The **COUNTIFS** function returns the number of cells in one or more
>   collections that satisfy given conditions (one condition per
>   collection).
>
> `COUNTIFS(test-values, condition, test-values…, condition…)`
>
> *test-values*: A collection containing values to be tested. test-values can contain any value.
>
> *condition*: An expression that can include comparison operators, constants, the ampersand concatenation operator, and references. The
>   contents of the condition must be such that the result of comparing
>   the condition to another value results in the boolean value of TRUE or
>   FALSE.
>
> *test-values…*: Optionally include one or more additional collections containing values to be tested. Each test-values collection must be
>   followed immediately by a condition expression. This pattern of
>   test-values, condition can be repeated as many times as needed.
>
> *condition…*: If an optional collection of test-values is included, an additional expression that results in a boolean TRUE or FALSE. There
>   must be one condition expression following each test-values
>   collection; therefore, this function will always have an odd number of
>   arguments.
>
> *Notes*
>
> Each value in test-values is compared to the corresponding condition.
>   If the corresponding values in each collection meet the corresponding
>   conditional tests, the count is increased by 1.

Comment: That got me close enough; the commas needed to be semicolons, else it returned another syntax error. Changed that, and it now works perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you had different delimiters.  This is for US version.  Glad it worked!  Of course you can use as many conditions as you want, get creative!  Cheers!

Comment: No worries; as I said you got me very close, and all I needed to do was fix the delimiters.